# cocos2d convert coordinates

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, coordinates

I am developing a cocos2d game and i am a little confused with the coordinate system.  I have another application which i use to build levels with it but it has different coordinates. The coordinate (0,0) is in the top left corner and not in bottom left corner like in cocos2d. What is the easiest way to translate the coordinates to cocos2d space? Can i just substract the Y coordinate from the level height? Or is there any simpler way? Is the cocos2d coordinate system left handed or right handed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure UIKit has it's origin (0, 0) in the top left corner as well, so you should be able to call:

`[[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:yourpoint];`

And that will convert it to the same coordinate system as cocos2d.